# Bash script does not read ARG and ENV from docker file

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to set some environment variables for the building phase of my docker file.

[This](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/#:%7E:text=ENV%20values%20are%20available%20to,persist%20in%20the%20next%20command.) article claims that if you set an `ARG` and use it in `ENV` that `ENV` can be dynamically assigned and would be available to the remaining `RUN` commands that use bash.

This is my docker file:

```
ARG AuthSecret=some_auth_secret_here
ARG KeycloakClientSecret=some_keycloak_secret_here
ARG KeycloakIssuer=https://accounts.example.com/realms/Production

FROM company/custom-image:latest as builder

ENV AUTH_SECRET $AuthSecret
ENV KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET $KeycloakClientSecret
ENV KEYCLOAK_ISSUER $KeycloakIssuer

COPY . /

RUN chmod 777 /scripts/build.sh \
    && bash /scripts/build.sh
```

As you can see, I copy everything inside the docker image, and then run a `/scripts/build.sh` file.

In that file, I have this line:

```
echo "*************** $KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET"
```

And this is what I get:

> "***************

In other words, the environment variables set in previous lines in the docker file are not available to my bash script.

What should I do?

**Update**:

Even adding this line of code does not work:

```
RUN echo "-------------------- $KeycloakClientSecret ---------------- $KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET"
```

This is the output I get:

> "--------------------  ----------------

Comment: `ARG` that appear before the first `FROM` can only be used in `FROM` lines and to provide defaults.  `ARG` needs to be placed after the `FROM` line, maybe repeated in a multi-stage build, to be seen in the actual image.